# Does the government of South Korea have any plans to address their fertility rate, which is currently the lowest in the world?

Tags: demographics, south-korea

South Korea currently has a fertility rate of 0.84, which is the lowest in the world and **significantly** below the minimum required to sustain their population. Given this strong reduction, does their government have any plans on how to increase it in the future?

2024 update: the 2023 fertility rate was 0.72, so it keeps falling.

Comment: I really dislike questions like this because they presume that this is something the government sees as an issue and therefore plans to solve. How do you know the government wants to increase it?

Comment: @uberhaxed they will see a *drastic* working age population collapse very soon if they don't do something about this. Literally their whole economy would collapse at these hyper-low birth rates, this is not sustainable in the slightest.

Comment: @JonathanReez Perhaps you should update your question and add that as a context, because all schools teach is how a growing population is a danger to planet earth. So most are not aware of the disadvantage of an ageing population that isn't being replenished in a "balanced" manner.

Comment: They give some sort of a "baby allowance" to new parents. They increased that amount quite a bit recently. Apart from this, I don't know what else they're doing.

Comment: Please note that 0.84 is by one metric, the World Bank's.  By the more customary UN metrics, [SK sits at 1.1.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependencies_by_total_fertility_rate).  They're still the lowest, just a little bit less outlier than one might expect when one is used to UN numbers and World Bank ones get used instead.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica their [births count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_South_Korea#Registered_births_and_deaths) paints a very bleak picture regardless of the methodology. A ~2x drop in the number of births over the past 2 years. They're headed for a complete disaster if something is not done.

Comment: The 0.84 figure is from 2021.  [It went down to 0.81 in 2022.](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-62670717)

Comment: As is the question is unclear: Who is "South Korea"? When talking about Iran or Saudi Arabia, the country name may refer to a single person or a small group, who decide for the rest of the population. South Korea is a democratic country, so the policy of its government (supposedly) reflects the desires of its population... who do not want to have children.

Comment: @RogerVadim The question is clearly about government policies.

Comment: @sfxedit but the government represents the people? Or does it presents interests of someone else? The question suggests that the interests of government or some abstract entity called "South Korea" are not those of the population. This might be the case, but it is hard to prove... or at least requires an additional layer of reasoning (e.g., how low birth rates are not in the interest of a certain politician or political group.)

Comment: Population is not only determined by fertility rate. Life expectancy or immigration also play a role. Especially lifting the retirement age can alleviate problems with declining working population sizes. You just don't retire but work until you die instead.

Comment: @Trilarion: pensions are extremely small in Korea, hardly better than [post-]Soviet countries $179; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pension_policy_in_South_Korea#Basic_Old-Age_Pension

Comment: @sfxedit *schools teach is how a growing population is a danger to planet earth* Countries with collapsing populations are hardly very significant in overall overpopulation burden for the planet.  Most of absolute world population growth is accounted for by 5-10 countries in Asia and Africa.  None of which are SK.  What SK does on this front is irrelevant though its emissions per capita do matter.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica 'Collapsing populations' can trigger an economic fallout that can have global impact in our connected world economy. So no, the world can't just treat it as an SK or Japanese problem. Already we in India, with 1.4 billion people are also worrying about our ageing population, and rising unemployment amongst our youth and the impact all this will have on our economy in the future. Collapsing economies can also shatter the self-esteem of a nation as we saw with Germany (triggering WW 1 and 2), and can now see somewhat with Russia too.

Comment: @sfxedit I don't see South Korea go on a rampage anytime soon, not with these neighbors. Apart from economic problems a certain population decline should be acceptable. Just see it this way: more housing space for everyone and nobody needs to build new for that.

Comment: @Trilarion If only economics were that simple - more housing space is irrelevant if you cannot afford to buy a house. An economy in downturn reduces the buying power of the population, especially the weaker section.

Comment: @sfxedit supply and demand will eventually take over still, as long as foreigners are banned from buying real estate

Comment: @sfxedit I see the problems associated with a rapid decline in population. Just wanted to add that there are upsides too, for example more space per person. Otherwise overpopulation would never be a problem.

Comment: @JonathanReez It isn't as simple as that as the rich property owners will instead pivot to prioritise renting it, than selling.

Comment: @sfxedit In the long run there so far hasn't been a single city in history which suffered a population decline without also suffering a reduction in rent/purchase prices over the long term. I don't see why South Korea (or any other country) would suddenly break this pattern.

Comment: "Population not wanting to have children" is not an impenetrable obstacle in a democratic society: they all had taxes last time I've checked.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently the current government thinks more money on the same kind of policies that didn't work too well before *will* actually solve (or at least ameliorate) the problem, as NPR [relates](https://www.npr.org/2023/03/19/1163341684/south-korea-fertility-rate):

> President Yoon Suk Yeol said in September that the government has poured more than $200 billion into programs to support new mothers in the past 16 years alone, only to watch the fertility rate drop more than 25% in that time span.
>
> At the center of the government response is a pledge to increase the stipend given to parents with a child under the age of 1 from 300,000 won per month (about $230) to 1 million won ($765) by 2024.
>
> The country's child care policies are also among the best in the world, according to UNICEF, and continue to expand. The government announced plans in January to increase the paid parental leave period from one year to a year-and-a-half.

Another [source](https://www.asahi.com/ajw/articles/14338131) (Asahi Shimbun) gives that (old) figure as "224 trillion won since 2006 on measures against the falling fertility rates" (which checks out to about 168 billion USD at current exchange rates.) Asahi also says that the problem is more acute in Seoul, with its high cost of living, and high cost of education, where the birth rate is only 0.64. Places (outside Seoul) with free kindergarten seem to fare better. E.g it was 1.28 in the new administrative capital of [Sejong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sejong_City).

However, getting high-tech businesses to spread more through the country has proven a more difficult task, despite [some plans](https://www.theargus.org/news/articleView.html?idxno=2290) in that direction too.

> Knowledge-based industries with high added value, such as information and communication technology, are concentrated in the Seoul capital area, while manufacturing, where the value is decreasing day by day, is based in the rural areas.

As explained further in that piece, the government is trying to create more "techno valleys" outside of [Pangyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangyo_Techno_Valley). (Pangyo is only about 20km from Seoul center, according to Google Maps, so essentially part of its greater metropolitan area.) The same is true for higher-up corporate jobs:

> most companies have their headquarters located in Seoul, and mid-sized companies that were in some regional areas are also moving their headquarters to the Seoul capital area. Of the top 100 companies by market capitalization in 2022, 86 companies have their headquarters located in the Seoul capital area. There is a clear difference between the Seoul capital area and the rural areas not only related to the location of corporate headquarters, but also in the quantity and quality of jobs. According to Job Korea, Korea's representative job offer site, as of May 5, 2022, 124,883 jobs were found in Seoul, 82,365 jobs in Gyeonggi province, and 18,166 jobs in Incheon. There was a total of 154,414 job announcements in the Seoul capital area, a huge difference from 63,483 jobs in non-Seoul capital areas. There were no places with more than 10,000 job postings in non-Seoul metropolitan cities or provinces. Even if we simply compare the absolute number of jobs, we can confirm that the Seoul capital area has far more jobs than non-metropolitan areas.
>
> As it is difficult to find a job in rural areas, many young people are moving to the Seoul capital area. Professor Kim Kyung-hoe of the Department of Education at Sungshin Women's University said, "The social and cultural infrastructure are all concentrated in Seoul, so most people want to live in Seoul. There are no fascinating jobs in rural areas,” he said. In conclusion, the problems of education and workplaces are exacerbating the expansion of the Seoul capital area.

More/cheaper childcare [seems](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/4/12/south-korea-splashes-the-cash-in-scramble-to-fix-fertility-crisis) to convince some, but not the majority of South Koreans:

> In a survey carried out for the Joongang Ilbo newspaper earlier this year, 27.4 percent of respondents said they believed the burden of childcare costs is the primary reason for low birth rates. Other cited reasons included job insecurity, housing instability and other economic factors. [...]
>
> In 2022, South Koreans’ spending on private education hit a new record, with total annual spending reaching 26 trillion won ($19.6bn) and almost 80 percent of all students receiving some form of private education.

It doesn't look like the SK government sees the rest of the socio-economic conditions as amenable to change, much, given their current plans. But critics point out these matter too:

> Professor Song Da-yeong, a social welfare professor at Incheon National University, said cash allowances were not a long-term solution. [...]
>
> South Korea has some of the longest work hours among developed countries and is ranked in the Economist’s annual glass-ceiling index as the worst OECD country for women to pursue equal opportunities in the workplace.
>
> “It needs to include policies such as using up all parental leave available, reduced work hours and flexible work arrangements,” Song said, emphasising the need for an environment where women are not “kicked out of the labour market” after giving birth.
>
> Although South Korea’s traditionally patriarchal attitudes are gradually changing, women are often still expected – and in some cases feel obligated – to become full-time mothers after giving birth.

Comment: [Hikikomori: Why S Korea is paying young recluses to leave home](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-65554271).