# South Korea's birth rate is the lowest in the world - why aren't they doing anything about it?

Tags: demographics, south-korea

If any other government had the lowest fertility rate in the world, they would feel really scared for the future of their nation and start working hard.

But the South Korean government has done nothing exceptional - as if they have been ordered not to.

If I was President of South Korea, I would just stop everything and address the nation, lower the cost of living, rent etc - anything in my power to stop my people from going extinct.

Why isn't the South Korean president doing more? Their fertility rate is dangerously low.

Comment: What exactly would be the outcome of such a meeting? A specific policy? Why hold a meeting with the whole country instead of doing what you're elected to do? More over, while birth rates declining generally leads to lower population, population does not decline unless the death rate exceed the new population rate. And you can acquire more population without births (look at the immigration policies of countries in north America).

Comment: South Korea's population *is* projected to decline, but that decline is projected to level out at about 28 million. It's a problem, but it's not the existential threat this question makes it out to be.

Comment: A rather related Q asked before https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/79716/does-the-government-of-south-korea-have-any-plans-to-address-their-fertility-rat

Comment: "Why isn't the South Korean president doing more?" Because South Korean voters don't want him/her to do more, probably.

Comment: Not only related "Does the government of South Korea have any plans to address their fertility rate, which is currently the lowest in the world?" should fully answer this question. In general it sounds better to ask "Does X have plans for Y" instead of "Why doesn't X do Y".

Answer (score 4):

The image of a country's ruler as a well-intended father of the nation is at least somewhat outdated and generally plain wrong.

No matter wheither we talk about a working democracy, a degraded democracy, a traditional dictatorship or a full-featured monarchy, a ruler cannot do whatever they feel like right against their people's better judgement.

The reaction to an unpopular policy may range from people working less and paying less taxes, people emigrating, etc... all the way to people changing the ruler by election or by force.

A charismatic and determined leader may succeed in promoting some agenda to their citizens only to some degree.

That said, we are yet to see a country failing because of its declining population and the general person on the (S. Korean) street knows that pretty well.

Low birth rates and declining population is not something unheard of and examples are all over the world - ANY industrialized country has went from 4+ kids per woman to less than 2 kids per woman. We don't know how it would work in the long run, but there is a general understanding that the things will settle.

Humans (as well as other species) are known to react to lower population density with increased fertility.

In the past, a country outperforming its neighbor in population growth could simply overtake the less populous neighbor in a war. This is not the case anymore - generally because countries grossly outperforming others in population usually lack economic, industrial and military power.

In the long run, a persistent population decline may be deterimental for the economy, as well as to other important things. On the other hand, a population explosion can be equally bad and could happen sooner - things like undereducated, underemployed youth can diminish the gain of the increased workforce. The exact ballance is yet to be determined, but sharp swings in both fertility and mortality rate are known to be bad.

---

On the bright side, S. Korea may at some point unite with N. Korea (they both declare willingness and just cannot agree on the exact terms). Counted together, they are no more a statistical outlier (should we believe the N. Korean population data).

Answer (score 3):

The number of people in a country is not a good measure of that country's development or success. Instead you can look at how well the individuals are able to prosper. Do they have food and water? Are they safe and secure? Can work together? Can they get a sense of accomplishment? Can they self-actuate?  (ie Maslow's pyramid of needs)  You can measure these by indicators such as child-mortality, literacy, gdp, gini and so on.

If the reason for a declining population is a lack of basic needs, this can be a concern.  But this is not the case for South Korea.

Simply "having lots of people" isn't a good measure of success, if those people are unhappy.  Now there are concerns with a declining, and ageing population but these are not about the numbers, but about productivity, and the cost in social care - a complex but separate issue.

Your suggestion that South Koreans will "go extinct" isn't borne out by the evidence.  Koreans choose to have fewer children because of the high costs involved in raising children when the population is high.  There is no reason to suppose that the population would drop to zero!

Comment: ok, but the situation is so bad, that if they dont change it - nobody will exist to self-actuate themselves

Comment: No. That is not true. The situation is not so bad. There are plenty of people in Korea.